# how to remove a specific word from a row of one column and paste the removed substring to another column using python

Tags: python, pandas, stop-words

remove words = ['apple','banana']

col A
apple is good

after removal

col A
is good

col removed word

apple

Comment: please edit and aske the question again as it makes no sense...

Comment: just look at Michael' solution, then i hope it would make sense to u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

remove_words = ['apple','banana']

df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['apple is good'],
    ['banana is bad'],
    ['banana is good and apple is bad']
], columns=['col A'])
print(df)

df['col removed word'] = df['col A'].apply(
    lambda t: [w for w in remove_words if w in t.split()]
)
df['col A'] = df['col A'].apply(
    lambda t: ' '.join([w for w in t.split() if w not in remove_words])
)
print(df)
```

prints

| index | col A |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | apple is good |
| 1 | banana is bad |
| 2 | banana is good and apple is bad |

| index | col A | col removed word |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | is good | apple |
| 1 | is bad | banana |
| 2 | is good and is bad | apple,banana |